# Best way to trigger javascript error to go to catch block

Tags: javascript, rest, code-quality, error-handling, error-detection

I have a couple of doubts regarding the quality of my code. I'm working on a helper function (for KoaJS) where I'm validating a Firebase ID token. If it is valid, I return the decoded token; otherwise I return an authorization error.

Also, if the function is initialized to request email to be verified, it will check if email of Firebase account is already verified. If there's an authorization error (token has expired, token is invalid, etc), it returns an error with the property codePrefix equals to auth. I use that to verify if it is an authorization error or any other kind of error.

```
validateIDToken: function (emailValidated = false) {

    return async (request) => {

        const { idtoken } = request.headers;

        try {
            const decodedToken = await firebaseApp.auth().verifyIdToken(idtoken);
            if (emailValidated && !decodedToken.emailValidated) {
                throw { codePrefix: 'auth' };
            }

            return decodedToken;
        }
        catch (err) {
            if (err.codePrefix === 'auth') {
                throw Boom.unauthorized();
            }

            throw Boom.badImplementation('Error validating ID Token');
        }
    };
}
```

My doubts are:

- Is it correct to return a JSON with codePrefix property to manually throw an error and go to the catch clause? Do you think it is a better/more elegant way to do it?
- Is it correct to not having a default return statement, but to rely that it will return something in the normal flow or in the catch clause? I don't want to fall in the scenario of having multiple return/throw clauses in a single function.
- Do you think it is ok to default catch clause to throw a 500 error (missing a logger error statement)?

Comment: If there's more than one way, what is your criteria for "best"?

Comment: @ErikEidt The cleanest way to do it, maybe following a certain design pattern I don't know about